# Как правильно указать путь к файлу для require?

Tags: php, html

Если файл.php, который нужно подключить, находится в той же папке, то он подключается, если в корне сайта, то нет.

`<?php require "header.php;" ?>` - работает

`<?php require "/header.php;" ?>` - не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

require работает в файловой системе, а не от корня сайта.
чтобы включить файл из корня сайта вам нужено указать к нему правильный путь:

```
require getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . '/header.php';
```